# Samsung Gear VR activate rear camera

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, oculus, virtual-reality

I'm trying to create a simple native app similiar to Passthrough app, I'm using the Passthrough.java class, but when I call the startCameraPreview method nothing happens.

My objective is to activate the rear camera of Galaxy Note 4 and show the preview using the Gear VR.

The camera preview seems to have started, there's no log errors, but all that I can get is a black screen and a recurring message in logcat "W/QCamera2HWI: processMetaCallback: lls not enabled, no ops here".

Someone knows the meaning of that message?

EDIT:
I've found a useful framework created by Samsung, http://www.gearvrf.org/ through this I've got the camera working.

Comment: Can't help but would be interested to hear if you solved this.

Comment: Could you share more details how did you got the camera working (which class did you use)?

Comment: @AlexLima Inside the Gear VR Framework there are several samples, one of those it's called [scene-objects](https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/tree/master/GVRf/Sample/scene-objects).
 I take inspiration using that sample, anyway the flow is simple:
Declare your android Camera object and pass it to a GVRCameraSceneObject and you're done!

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me.

Comment: please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others know that this issue is resolved

Comment: @lockstock my solution was the comment posted on Nov 6 2015

Comment: @Bonch I know that, but in the search results this issue appears unresolved, so if you add your solution as an actual answer and then mark it as accepted, other users will know that it is unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a useful framework created by Samsung, http://www.gearvrf.org/ through this I've got the camera working.
Inside the Gear VR Framework there are several samples, one of those it's called scene-objects. I take inspiration using that sample, anyway the flow is simple: Declare your android Camera object and pass it to a GVRCameraSceneObject